# How to change the image a source is associated with

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Is there anyway that I can put an image on my site that changes.
I know how to change the source of an image element. What I mean is like:
the image is located here 
http://mywebsite.com/image.png

this doesn't change but I want the actual image to change.
More examples:
https://huggle.jdf2.org/

This site creates a bbcode element that contains the img username.png

```
[url=http://huggle.jdf2.org/hug/username][img]http://huggle.jdf2.org/sig/username.png[/img][/url]
```

This image changes depending on how many huggles you have.

How would I do this?

Comment: your first link looks a little bit broken. Also, I don't really get why you want the image src to stay the same. what's wrong with username02.png, username03.png etc?

Comment: Because if I was to embed it in say bbcode. I am wondering how I would make it so that I can change the image without changing the reference link.

Comment: I don't know much about bbcode, But I still don't see what the problem is with the image src changing. just change the bbcode to have the new src. at any rate. I don't believe it's possible to do client side. You'll need to use a server side language like php or node.js to overwrite the image file on the server.

Comment: are users downloading the image to their computer? because if that's what they are doing. your page can rename the file being downloaded. so that it downloads "username45.png" from the server and defaults to "username.png" in the Save As dialog when the user downloads it.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the image source URL with:

```
var yourURLHere = 'ADD YOUR URL HERE';
image.src = yourURLHere;
```

If you want the your image to randomly change, you can use Math.random() to select a random URL from an array.

Example: Random teddy bear images (see below).

```html
<image src="#" id="my-image"/>
Click to change image randomly.
<button id="my-btn">Change it!</button>
<script>
var imageURLs = [
  'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4e/da/9f/4eda9f56de08463bcc18d154f654ab6d.jpg',
  'http://lcdn.inthelighturns.com/media/product/e85/sweet-memories-blue-teddy-bear-urn-b83.jpg',
  'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3c/80/3c/3c803ce72e8c0325d7ea0fcd32f81ed9.jpg',
  'http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Cartoon-teddy-bear-clipart.gif',
'http://cliparts.co/cliparts/rcn/Kox/rcnKox65i.png',
'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f2/d6/25/f2d6258ef0fa6de2160778066ccec832.jpg',
'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/90/3a/6c/903a6c59c0a2f42e7d6e7cb9427a8337.jpg',
'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/a9/ee/30/a9ee30a4f8d196a111aa5c3db7b13b6e.jpg',
'http://cdn3.volusion.com/9nxdj.fchy5/v/vspfiles/photos/BB-1433-2.jpg?1415360799'
];
var image = document.getElementById('my-image');
    
function pickRandomURL() {
  return imageURLs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length)];
}
    
 image.src = pickRandomURL();
 image.width = 200;

var btn = document.getElementById('my-btn');
  btn.onclick = function() {
  image.src = pickRandomURL();
  image.width = 200;
};
</script>
```